# Why when I use Plug and Play ( PnP ) yarn feature workspaces symlinking stops working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, yarn-v2

I have two packages in my monorepository and I would like to use workspaces feature. When I use standard mode ( with `node_modules` ) I can import data from one package to another. When I use Plug and Play feature, for some reason after `yarn install` symlinks doesn't appear as it happens with `node_modules`.

That is why I have an Error "`Cannot find module X`", when I try to start `index.js` script inside the `first` package.

[image]

**Root's package.json**

[image]

**First package's package.json**

[image]

**Second package's package.json**

[image]

**Second package's index.js**

[image]

**First package's index.js**

[image]

---

This is a working version. I need specially to set nodeLinker to node-modules in `.yarnrc.yml`. As you can see, `first` and `second` symlinks are created.

[image]
[image]

But when I try to switch it to `pnp`, there is no any symlinks. And when I try to import something from another package, I get an error. For example in the screenshot below I run the `node index.js` command.

[image]
[image]

[image]

---

## And finally the question ! How to use workspaces with PnP yarn feature ? Is it possible in general ?

I try to run a script from a package, which imports data from another one using `yarn workspaces` and `plug and play` features.

I expect this won't fail.